ASP.NET Core 8 Razor Pages Routing with Parameter conflicting PageModels
I'm working with ASP.NET Core 8.0.8. I have various models that represent different tables in a connected database. I have a Table.cshtml razor page that will take the name of a table as a parameter (see below) and display all the relevant information from the database associated with the provided table, which works great.
Table.cshtml:
@page "/{model}"
@model TableModel

I also have a Form.cshtml razor page that will take the name of a table as a parameter along with a form type (see below) and provides the appropriate option depending on the form type provided.
Form.cshtml:
@page "/{model}/{form}"
@model FormModel

My problem occurs when I try to access other pages in my application such as Login.cshtml or Index.cshtml. If I navigate to /Login for instance, it will load the correct page (Login.cshtml) and page model (LoginModel), but for some reason also calls the table page model (TableModel) which causes some conflicts.
I would like to keep parameters as route data within the URL as there will be many separate search query values later on. And I would like to keep the route templates as documented to keep the URL simpler and more readable for the end user.
Ideally I would like the following routes to work as such:
/ -> Index.cshtml with IndexModel
/Login -> Login.cshtml with LoginModel
/Table1 -> Table.cshtml with TableModel
/Table2 -> Table.cshtml with TableModel
/Table1/Create -> Form.cshtml with FormModel
/Table2/Edit -> Form.cshtml with FormModel
/Error/401 -> Error.cshtml with ErrorModel

Here is my current Program.cs:
// Program.cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Pages").AllowAnonymousToPage("/Pages/Error");
});

var app = builder.Build();

// Production IIS folder
app.UsePathBase("/inventoryDEV");

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment()) {
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
} else app.UseStatusCodePagesWithRedirects("/Error/{0}");

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

//app.UseAuthentication();
//app.UseAuthorization();

//app.UseSession();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();

I tried explicitly specifying the route template in all pages to no avail.
// Index.cshtml
@page "/"
@model IndexModel

// Login.cshtml
@page "/Login"
@model LoginModel

// Error.cshtml
@page "/Error/{status?}"
@model ErrorModel

I also noticed that sometimes the conflicting routing would break my CSS. For whatever reason it would send the current HTML page as, for instance, table.css.
My table.css file would look like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <!-- A literal HTML file instead of CSS -->
</html>

UPDATE:
It seems this RenderSection() call in my _Layout.cshtml is causing problems, but I'm not sure why. Removing it solves my issue but I lose the page-specific CSS styling functionality I was using.
<head>
    <title>@ViewData["Title"]</title>
    @RenderSection("Styles", false)
</head>

With the RenderSection call in place, the FormModel gets initialized as it seems the {model} parameter is "Form" and the {form} parameter is "dashboard.css" (which is the name of the CSS file I am sending) for some reason.
// Index.cshtml Styles section
@section Styles {
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@Href("~/css/dashboard.css")" asp-append-version="true" />
}


Razor Pages prioritizes exact matches over generic matches based on my test. I created a new razor page web app, and I added Index.cshtml, Table.cshtml, Form.cshtml, Login.cshtml and they have routing definition @page, @page "/{model}", @page "/{model}/{form}", @page "/Login". When I visit / or /index it will show index page, when I visit  /login it will go to login page, when I visit /table or some other unexisiting view name, it will go to table page. I didn't face the conflict you mentioned for some reason also calls the table page model (TableModel)

To avoid the conflict, I'm afraid you could try to change the generic matching rule from @page "/{model}" to @page "/showtable/{model}". Pls correct me if I  misunderstand your issue.

@TinyWang I expected it to prioritize exact matches but it seems to be behaving oddly for me. When I visit /Login it will send the correct Login.cshtml view and call the correct LoginModel controller and OnGet() handler but for whatever reason also seems to initialize the TableModel controller (calls its constructor).
And adding /showtable/ beforehand is definitely a viable option, I was just hoping to avoid having to do that to keep my URLs simpler. Wanted to see if there was a way I could force literals prioritization in the mapping or something like that.

Thank you for your confirmation, but I'm puzzled that what do you mean about the controller? In razor page web app there's no controller since it's not MVC....Maybe this is the reason why you could trigger TableModel at the same time?

@TinyWang My apologies, I wasn't sure what to call it. I'm used to MVC terminology but I am talking about the public TableModel() constructor incorrectly being called in my public class TableModel : PageModel class after the public LoginModel() constructor in my public class LoginModel : PageModel was already correctly called.

@TinyWang Please see the update on my submission. I think I found what is causing the additional incorrect PageModel to trigger.

Thank you for your update. I had a test in my side to add @RenderSection("Styles", false) in my _Layout.cshtml  element, then add your @section Styles section in my Index.cshtml, but when I visit /index or / I can't reproduce your issue. I'm afraid you are using a different route? Are you trying to visit /index/dashboard then in your Index.cshtml you will check the routing parameter and render the css? By the way, how about trying @await RenderSectionAsync instead of @RenderSection?

@TinyWang no luck with @await RenderSectionAsync but that was a good idea. I am just visiting / when having the issue so I don't think the route should be different than what you are testing. I think I will just follow @CreativeGuy888's suggestion to move all my CSS to one file as that seems to be working. Thank you for all your assistance.

Like a previous commenter, I also created a new razor page web app with your specified pages and route templates. In my tests, each routing worked as expected and I was not able to replicate the conflict you face. That said, I would recommend doing the following:

Remove the following line from your Program.cs:

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options => {
    options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Pages").AllowAnonymousToPage("/Pages/Error");
});


You already call builder.Services.AddRazorPages();, so this could be causing issues with the routing.


Try deleting your .suo file. This is known to help clear random issues occurring with Visual Studio. See Delete Your_Solution_FileName.suo file.

You mention using a RenderSection to call the appropriate CSS file for a specific page and omitting this seems to solve your issue. I would suggest looking more into this as I'm not sure why a CSS file would be causing your routing to break, but less strange things have happened. You could also try:



Verifying that each @section Styles correctly references your desired CSS file (make sure the href maps correctly).
Putting all your CSS into one file and just have the _Layout.cshtml reference that.
Looking into CSS isolation.


Check external factors:


Ensure Visual Studio is up-to-date
Try to disable any VS extensions
Check your project file and make sure everything is as expected
Try to update any packages or libraries you reference
Try to update Windows


As a last resort you can always recreate your project and verify as you go that the routing is still working as expected. Alternatively, you may find that commenting out certain sections will lead you to the problem area.


Thank you for the suggestions. I removed the secondary AddRazorPages() call and tried deleting the .suo file but that didn't seem to solve my issue. I think I will go with your suggestion to just move all my CSS into one file as removing the RenderSection call does, for whatever reason, fix my issue.
